# multiple outputs in a single string in Terraform

Tags: terraform

Terraform provides excellent documentation for displaying outputs including AWS.

```
output "ip" {
  value = "${aws_eip.ip.public_ip}"
}
```

That would in term provide something like

```
ip = 50.17.232.209
```

what I would like to get if possible is something like:

```
public_ip = x.x.x.x and private_ip = y.y.y.y
```

in one line as opposed to separate items. I have tried something like this:

```
output "public ip and private ip" {
  value = "${aws_eip.ip.public_ip}"
  value = "${aws_eip.ip.private_ip}"
}
```

Currently, It's working if I split them up like this:

```
output "public_ip" {
  value = "${aws_eip.ip.public_ip}"
}

output "private_ip" {
  value = "${aws_eip.ip.private_ip}"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work, although splitting them up probably makes most sense:

```
output "public ip and private ip" {
  value = "public_ip = ${aws_eip.ip.public_ip} and private_ip = ${aws_eip.ip.private_ip}"
}
```

Maybe you have to tune it a bit to have the formatting as you prefer, but I hope that my answer at least shows that there is nothing special compared to string interpolation somewhere else..